# How do you merge multiple static linked libraries into a single dll given each static lib defines exported functionality (vc++ 2008)?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-c++, function

How do you merge multiple static linked libraries into a single dll given each static lib defines exported functionality (vc++ 2008)?.

In a multi project layout existing out of a single dll project and multiple sub projects that are linked in statically (in the dll project). Despite being marked as __declspec(export) some of the symbols in the sub-projects (.lib) refuse to have their symbols exported in the final dll.

Generating a .def file and marking the symbols explicitly for exportation could solve this problem. However identifying which of the symbols are marked as __declspec( export ) proofs a problem. Due large number of exported classes/function and primarily name mangling maintaining a list by hand is a unfordable process thus generating the list of symbols, that were marked for export, would be the only viable option.

Is there an utility or compiler directive could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a DEF file.

Always use a DEF file.

Never fail to use a DEF file.

Just accept that a DEF file is the thing to use.

Stop using __declspec(dllexport), and use a dang-dratted def file already.

Also don't export classes. Export those class members which need to be exported only. And use a DEF file to do it.

Seriously, if you export classes without a DEF file, the function names will be several times longer than the actual program data. You should to use ordinals for exporting C++ member functions.

Comment: However you still need to supply a mangled name i.e. internal name. Function signatures are likely to change in the development cycle, and so are the managed names. How do you propose to manage those w/o extern "c"?

Comment: @phr34k, you will have a test harness which `#include`s the class and function definitions and links to the DLL's export lib. Every time you reference a function, you will get a linker error which gives the mangled name. (If you have no test for the function just take it's address `void* p = (void*) &ClassName::FunctionName`). Add that mangled name to the DEF file with an ordinal and the NONAME attribute. (You will have to remove the `__imp` prefix). You will that way guarantee you have exported every function the test harness references, and thereby tested the DEF file.

Comment: This answer miss some documentation and example :-(

Answer (score 2):

After bit trial and error I found that using the lib /def command can be utilized to generate an import library and export file. It appears that the export file contains all symbols that are marked with __declspec(dllexport). Subsequently the .exp file can be inspected with dumpbin and used as a reference to generate a module definition file.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 there is a new way of doing this, by using the linker option `/WHOLEARCHIVE`

It's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/wholearchive-include-all-library-object-files?view=vs-2017)

> The `/WHOLEARCHIVE` option forces the linker to include every object
>   file from either a specified static library, or if no library is
>   specified, from all static libraries specified to the LINK command. To
>   specify the `/WHOLEARCHIVE` option for multiple libraries, you can use
>   more than one `/WHOLEARCHIVE` switch on the linker command line. By
>   default, the linker includes object files in the linked output only if
>   they export symbols referenced by other object files in the
>   executable. The `/WHOLEARCHIVE` option makes the linker treat all object
>   files archived in a static library as if they were specified
>   individually on the linker command line.